# Trouble with Datetime2 and php

Tags: php, sql

I've been tasked with updating my University IT department's inventory site. The inventory is stored in a Microsoft SQL Server, and the website's in php. Before, they used a Date datatype called lastUpdated to store when a piece of inventory's page was last updated. Now they want a timestamp added, so I changed the lastUpdated column to datetime2.

I'm trying to edit the php to reflect this change, but it gives me the following error when I submit the form (click the "add inventory" button) : Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I have limited knowledge of php. My supervisor knows this, but said I should do it for the learning experience. I tried googling the error, but (most likely due to my lack of experience) nothing has worked. If someone could help me out in this I'd be so appreciative.

Going to try and paste the relevant code without the extra inventory stuff.

```
$_POST['lastUpdated'] = sanitize($_POST['lastUpdated']);
<div class='row'>
          <label for='lastUpdated'>Last Updated:</label>
          <input type='text' id='ldate' name='lastUpdated' class='readonly' size='20' value='".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' readonly />  
          <span id='ldateInfo'>Last updated in inventory</span>
</div>      

$params = array(&$_POST['contactID'], &$_POST['propertyNum'], &$_POST['serialNum'], &$_POST['bldg'], &$_POST['room'], &$_POST['offCampus'], &$_POST['description'], &$_POST['status'], &$_POST['dateAdded'], &$_POST['lastUpdated'], &$_POST['computerName'], &$_POST['warrantyDate']);
    $tsql = "INSERT INTO dbo.tblInventory (contactID, propertyNum, serialNum, bldg, room, offCampus, description, status, dateAdded, computerName, warrantyDate, lastUpdated) 
            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $insertInventory = $conn->prepare($tsql);
    $insertInventory->execute($params);
```

Comment: that's an SQL error. Whatever you're doing is sending an invalid date/time string to SQLserver. But since you don't show the DB code, we can't really help.

Comment: There's not really any code to show. I'm in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, and it just shows lastUpdated as datetime2(7).

Comment: @user3813250 I think he is talking about the SQL query you use to try to insert the datetime and the PHP to *generate* the datetime.

Comment: Oh, that makes way more sense. I'll add it in

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward function available in php to get MSSQL Datetime2 string.

I would suggest you to create Stored proceduure on MSSQL DB.
You can pass required data to the procedure.
get lastUpdated as current date and fire a insert query in stored procured.

Answer (score 0):

Found stupidly simple solution: The values in $params didn't match up with the values in $tsql. Much crying ensued.